# R: Problem with bandwith selection of kernel density

Tags: r, bandwidth, kernel-density

I want to calculate the optimal bandwith value for my kernel density estimation. I have a .csv with two columns (longitude and latitude). I tried several different functions but always get different errors. So far i tried:

```
h.amise(x, deriv.order = 0)
```

which give my following error:  argument 'x' must be numeric and need at least 3 data points
However, I checked my dataframe and it is numeric.

Then I tried:

```
dpik(x)
```

which give my following error: 'list' object cannot be coerced to type 'double'

Is is wrong to use a .csv as dataframe with two columns or what can be the issue?

Comment: What is `x`? A data frame is a list object. The list may contain numeric objects, e.g. latitude and longitude. Show the code you used to create `x` and then use `dput(head(x, 10))` and paste the results into your question.

Comment: `x` is my .csv file. I used `x <- read.csv(("~/acacia.csv"), sep = ";")` ro read it in. The results for `dput(head(x, 10))` are: `structure(list(long = c(-71.230502, -70.496428, -73.103851, -70.570612, 
-73.052153, -70.87463, -71.577362, -71.382384, -70.637829, -73.1616
), lat = c(-34.539237, -33.361865, -36.733704, -33.378587, -36.801315, 
-34.658633, -33.121937, -34.44963, -33.425878, -40.597911)), row.names = c(NA, 
10L), class = "data.frame")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your sample data:

```
library(kedd)
library(KernSmooth)

h.amise(x$long)
# 
# Call:     Aymptotic Mean Integrated Squared Error
# 
# Derivative order = 0
# Data: x$long (10 obs.);   Kernel: gaussian
# AMISE = 0.02761525;   Bandwidth 'h' = 1.57264

h.amise(x$lat)
# 
# Call:     Aymptotic Mean Integrated Squared Error
# 
# Derivative order = 0
# Data: x$lat (10 obs.);    Kernel: gaussian
# AMISE = 0.01352194;   Bandwidth 'h' = 3.37266

dpik(x$long)
# [1] 0.4912055
dpik(x$lat)
# [1] 1.079109
```

Read the manual pages `?h.amise` and `?dpik` for the details. The functions take a single numeric vector as input.

Comment: Thank you very much. Do I have to built the mean between the two h values for my kernel density estimation?

Comment: You could try both and the mean and look at the results. They are based on different assumptions about the underlying data. Which to use in different circumstances would be a question for CrossValidated.